# Javascript code not being called/ not working properly

Tags: javascript, function

I have this javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function editHiddenInput(CarType)
{
 document.getElementById('sellingcarname') = CarType;
}

</script>
```

Hidden Input:

```
<input name="sellingcarname" id="sellingcarname" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Once it's called it's supposed to change the hidden input(sellingcarname) to text defined when the function is called using this button:

```
<div id="button"><input type="submit" onclick="editHiddenInput('rtv');" value="Sell" style="display: none; " /><span class="button">Sell<span></span></span></div>
```

However, it does not change the hidden input, so it's pretty useless, any help?

Comment: What `CarType` should be? If it is not a string, what do you expect?

Comment: @Bakudan good point. Try testing with document.getElementById('sellingcarname').value = 'test value';

Comment: Your submit button has `display: none`, so you can't click on it. How would the click event be activated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/BQEuZ/1/)

You need to put your function code noWrap(Head).

```
document.getElementById('sellingcarname').value = CarType;
```

You can change your hidden inputs value with this code.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
document.getElementById('sellingcarname').value = CarType;
```

**Update**

Sorry, I missed a couple other things with this code.

When you click on the submit button, if it is in a form, it will submit the form, and the next page load will clear out the value you set. Make sure you have this in your onclick attribute:

```
<input type="submit" 
    onclick="editHiddenInput('rtv'); return false;" 
    value="Sell" style="display: none; " />
```

Comment: The hidden input still remains empty

Comment: Have you inspected in chrome or firebug? Are you talking about an <input type="hidden" />, because I don't see on in your example.

Comment: I've inspected in chrome, that's how I find out whether it's set or not.<input name="sellingcarname" id="sellingcarname" type="hidden" value="" /> <-- That's in my example

Comment: @icktoofay, sorry, I'm used to handling events with jquery. Just trying to cover all bases here.

Comment: The button is not within a form, it's merely a button, now that I think about it, I don't need a submit type for it do i?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign the string to the element itself, you have to assign it to the `value` property:

```
document.getElementById('sellingcarname').value = CarType;
```

Comment: Still doesn't set it, perhaps the function is not being called properly?